# How to create a view from a table with these conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `BOOK_AUTHORS`. It has two columns:
`book_id | author_name`

Primary Key = (book_id + author_name)

This is because one book may have multiple authors.

I want to create a view from this where I can have book_id as the primary key and the author_name concatenated for multiple authors.

e.g. Book 'XYZ' has two authors namely 'ABC' and 'PQR'. so it has two rows in the current `BOOK_AUTHORS` table as shown below:

```
book_id | author_name
        |
XYZ     |   ABC
XYZ     |   PQR
```

After creating the view, I want to get this:

```
book_id | author_name
        |
XYZ     |   ABC, PQR
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Loop over the book ids first and then add them to an array, and then loop over the authors and use an in_array check to see if it's part of the array or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(author_name) WHERE book_id = 'XYZ';
```

Comment: I'd add a separator, something weird like a pipe if you want to explode it later or just a comma, like `GROUP_CONCAT(author_name SEPARATOR ', ')`

Comment: I didn't literally meant XYZ, there can be many such books and many such authors.. its a good starting point though..

Comment: But i am completely blank here now! :(

Comment: You can pass any variable agains XYZ.